# Can't add executable file to PATH in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, path, sublime-text-2

I have this in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/Downloads/sublimetext
export PATH
```

But `sublimetext` in the folder isn't added to the path. Sublime Text gives this output when submitted to the file command:

```
sublime_text: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

Comment: can you show the output of: `ps -p $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'`, `ls -lad ~/Downloads/sublimetext`, and `ls -la ~/Downloads/sublimetext/sublime_text`?

Comment: It looks the problem here is that your `PATH` statements aren't `source`d, so you need to make sure you do exactly that: `source ~/.bash_profile` and then look at `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PATH` contains directories, not executable files. Try `PATH=$PATH:~/Downloads`. Although, really, you shouldn't be putting your downloads directory in your path; move the executable somewhere appropriate. Make a `~/bin` directory, for example.

Comment: I've moved sublimetext to ~/bin and added that to my path. Thing is sublime text is a directory, which contains the binary file sublime_text. So I am already referencing a directory in my path, not a directory. Nevertheless it won't come up when i try to execute it from the shell.

Comment: So, be more specific about "won't come up". Exactly what happens? Is there an error message?

Comment: what I meant by it was that it isn't included in the path. I get a standard 'cmd not found' error if I try to execute the program from outside the directory it's stored in. I'm definitely declaring it correctly in bash_profile because if I do the same thing with another executable (a python script for example) it works and I can call it from anywhere. So you can see from this that the problem isn't with the file not being executable, or not adding it to the path correctly. Hopefully I'm being clear enough.

Comment: It sounds like your `PATH` still isn't right, then. Can you update your question with the output of `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are modifying wrong .bash_profile. If you are root user then you have to modify /root/.bash_profile.
Try sourcing as
`source /home/username/.bash_profile` or `source /root/.bash_profile`
and then check $PATH.

Please follow the summary at http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm#_Summary

Answer (score 0):

Is it set in permissions to be executable ? (`chmod o+x ~/Downloads/sublimetext/sublime_text` to make it)

Comment: I've been executing it with ./sublime_text so it is executable. I just tried your command and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

First off check if you should be using the 32-bit or 64-bit version.

Secondly create a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# sublime shell script
# make sure there is no spaces in path.

if [ -d "$HOME/Downloads/SublimeText2" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/Downloads/SublimeText2:$PATH"
fi

sublime_text $@
#EOS
```

Now drop it in your ~/bin and make it executable.

```
$ chmod +x sublime

~/Desktop$ sublime -h | head -1

Sublime Text 2 Build 2181
```